# Extracting data from a website using iMacros

Tags: imacros

I am really new to iMacros but seem to have a basic understanding of how it works.  However, I have two problems that I just can't seem to resolve. The iMacros loads from and executable service that is ran whenever needed to get information.  Once the data is extracted the service takes it and writes it to a file on the servers C drive.  This has been working fine up till about a month ago.  Amazon changed the website and now I can't get the script to cooperate.  All help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

1. The script does not extract the text, and
2. A new iMacros browser opens after each run-through of the script.

I have researched the internet, manipulated the script many different ways, and I have used the record option, as well as the wizard to create the script to extract the data.  I'm not sure what I am missing. My script is below.

```
VERSION BUILD=7401598
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/fba/revenue-calculator/index.html/ref=au_xx_cont_xx?ie=UTF8&lang=en_US
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:search-form ATTR=ID:search-string CONTENT={{Asin}}
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:search-products
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:update-fees-link
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Order<SP>Handling
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Pick<SP>&<SP>Pack
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Weight<SP>Handling
WAIT SECONDS=10
```

[image: Amazon FBA Calculator]

The text I need to extract is Order handling, Pick & Pack, Weight Handling.

Answer (score 1):

You should try placing EXTRACT=TXT after the commands. Also check the html of page and make a command if record doesn't work. If for example you have a link on a page this would be it's HTML code.

```
<a href="www.somestuff.com">click me</a>
```

iMacros to extract link and text from this are.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:www.somestuff.com EXTRACT=TXT

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:www.somestuff.com EXTRACT=HREF
```

There are few other variations but this is the main part. In your case this would be the proper code.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:search-products EXTRACT = TXT
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:update-fees-link EXTRACT = TXT
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Order<SP>Handling EXTRACT = TXT
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Pick<SP>&<SP>Pack EXTRACT = TXT
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Weight<SP>Handling EXTRACT = TXT
WAIT SECONDS=10
```

Try it and please use iMacros FireFox addon for this.

Edit:

You can declare one scraping macro in JavaScript.

```
var macroScrape;

macroScrape ="CODE:";
macroScrape +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:search-products EXTRACT = TXT";


iimPlay(macroScrape)
var text=iimGetLastExtract();

alert(text);
```

I use only once EXTRACT command in once macro. If I need more info scraped I use more macro codes declared as a variable in the example above. This could work if you know how to use it.

iMacros support is sometimes really slow.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding.  Even though we have a paid Enterprise license with iOpus, they haven't responded at all in the support forum or to the email I sent to their support email address.  I tried this and when it comes to TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:search-products EXTRACT = TXT the search button doesn't even click and there is no information loaded on the screen.  At the end of the run I still get "Error" (Asin number):  input text is in incorrect format."

Comment: In order to use this information you have to store it somehow. I will edit the text and show you the way.

Comment: I added a new answer which can help you.

Comment: Our service is written in c#.  The script was fine prior to page change by Amazon.  We don't use JavaScript

Comment: Well then you have to find some examples in C# and figure out where is the issue. I've seen C# iMacros projects but I don't have payed version to be able to code in C#. The procedure is the same. Declare macro as a variable and manipulate with it. Check this topic on forum http://forum.iopus.com/viewtopic.php?t=7561